# Very weird Normal behaviour

Tags: normals, geometry-nodes

So here we have seemingly two identical squares. The left one was created as a plane and then rotated 90 degrees to stay upright. The right one was created by deleting 4 vertices of a simple cube. On both I deleted the faces and left only vertices and edges.
[image]

Next I added a geometry node and made this simple setup:
[image]

And then in the spreadsheet, you can see the normals of these 2 identical squares. The one on the left gets the expected normals, but the one on the right the normals are totally off? And more surprisingly they are not identical to the left square, even though the square's geometry is seemingly identical. How is that possible?
[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The plane edges are centered in the object origin, but a face from the cube is not:

[image: No face edge extrusion]

With no face, there isn't a normal to calculate, should it point away from the center? towards it? or maybe to an axis? the best way would be using the vertex order and an option to rotate the direction, which would make it a curve.

Since there's no defined way to calculate the normals, it uses the object origin and the vertex position to get a normal.